# Parsing JSON from NSData with Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I want to parse data in array but I can't. Please let me know if you have any suggestion. Here is my data sample:

```
[{"ListSequence":1,"StarTime":"15.06.2016 09:00","WorkTime":15,"EndTime":"15.06.2016 09:15","Appointment":"","CustomerId":"12345","Name":"","Address":"bla bla"}, {"ListSequence":2,"StarTime":"15.06.2016 09:20","WorkTime":15,"EndTime":"15.06.2016 09:35","Appointment":"","CustomerId":"54321","Name":"","Address":"bla bla"}]
```

This is my function:

```
func parserJSON(data: NSData){
    var names = [String]()
    do {
        if let ipString = NSString(data:data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

            if let sequences = jsonDictionary["ListSequence"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for sequence in sequences {
                    if let name = jsonDictionary["Name"] as? String{
                        names.append(name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        ///alert
    }
}
```

Comment: your ListSequence is String and your response is array

Comment: The JSON is a Array at top level, not a dictionary.

Comment: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON  try this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON represents an array, not an object. Try this:

```
func parserJSON(data: NSData){
    var names = [String]()
    do {
        if let ipString = NSString(data:data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as! [AnyObject]
            names = json.map { ($0 as! [String: AnyObject])["Name"] as! String }
        }
    } catch {
        ///alert
        print(error)
    }
}
```

`NSJSONSerialization` is really verbose. Everything is an atomic value (i.e. `String`), an array (`[AnyObject]`) or a dictionary (`[String: AnyObject]`). if you want to convert, you have to do it one step at a time.

Comment: Now it is working. I really appreciate your help. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code like this. From `API` you are getting `Array` not `Dictionary`. So do changes like this

```
func parserJSON(data: NSData){
    var names = [String]()
    do {
        if let ipString = NSString(data:data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
             let jsonArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
             //Now try to iterate Array

        }
    } catch {
        ///alert
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use your data as **NSArray**

```
let jsonData:NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSArray
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be easiest for you:

```
extension NSData {
    func fromJSON(options:NSJSONReadingOptions = .AllowFragments) -> AnyObject? {
        return (try? (NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self, options: options)))
    }
}
```

That way you could just do:

```
data.fromJSON() as? [[String:AnyObject]]
```

Or whatever you type you want to cast to